# PHP IF Tag Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have below, its showing that this template can only be accessed by the inspector role. I want to add multi role to this. What would be the best option.

```
if ( !current_user_can ('inspector')) {
    get_template_part('error');
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Roles and capabilities are two different things in WP. current_user_can checks for capabilities, is it what you mean? If you really mean that you want to check against multiple roles you could use : if(array_intersect( ['author', 'role2''], (array) $user->roles) !== 0)

Comment: I wanted to limit the template by role, but the capabilities seems to be working. I have this link to an actual WP page. But the user access plugins dome seem to wort with pages that anything but the default template assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the question, but this will show the error template if the user is not an inspector or admin. You can chain as many && together as you need for each role.

```
if ( !current_user_can ('inspector') && !current_user_can('admin')) {
    get_template_part('error');
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @Terry And is correct: if you are "not an inspector, and not an admin", you are "neither an inspector nor an admin"; if you are "not an inspector, **or** not an admin", you might be an inspector but not an admin, or an admin but not an inspector.

Comment: That would be true, except the OP is using the negative in his if statement. So the statement reads, "if a user is NOT an inspector AND NOT an admin" show the error. If they are either one of those, that part will return false and the if block is not executed.

Comment: There is no problem here, as it's the code checking if the user is **not** an inspector **AND** **not** an admin. Code which need specific access will be below